# Get Jquery mobile version programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Is there a way to get the Jquery mobile version programmatically?

I've found two ways for regular Jquery, but nothing for JQuery mobile:

```
$.prototype.jquery
$.fn.jquery
```

How can I ensure that some sprecific JQM version is used on the current page?

Comment: `$.mobile.version`, that's it. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/qvqykteb/

Comment: @Omar I dont know why, but in my case, it only results "@VERSION". Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Omar for his comment,

```js
$.mobile.version
```

does the job.

Comment: This version field is available in jQuery mobile versions 1.1.0 RC 1 and up.